# Javaでじゃんけんプログラムを作る

Tags: java

Johnの手はグー、パー、チョキ、グー・・・と出力し、Paulの手はランダムに出力するプログラムを作成したいと思い、以下のようにしたのですが、Johnの手が期待しているのとは違って出力されてしまいます。
（ちなみに、このじゃんけんプログラムは３回先に勝ったほうが勝ちとしています）

どうすれば（OrderedComputerPlayerのどこをどう直せば）、期待している実行結果となりますか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
/** ジャンケン の通常のコンピュータ プレイヤ */
public class OrderedComputerPlayer extends Player {
    protected Hand  goo, choki, par;
    // 手を決めるときに使う乱数

    /** コンストラクタ, プレイヤの名前を指定する */
    public OrderedComputerPlayer(String name) {
    super(name);
    // 手を設定する
    goo = new Goo();
    choki = new Choki();
    par = new Par();
    
    }

    /** match回目の勝負のnum回目のプレイヤの手を出す
     *  Player の showHand をオーバーライド
     */
    public Hand showHand(int match, int num) {
        
    switch(num%4){
    case 1: return goo;
        case 2: return par;
        case 3: return choki; 
        case 0: return goo; 
        }num++;  return goo;
    }
}
```

```
/** ジャンケン の通常のコンピュータ プレイヤ */
public class NormalComputerPlayer extends Player {
    protected Hand  goo, choki, par;
    protected java.util.Random random; // 手を決めるときに使う乱数

    /** コンストラクタ, プレイヤの名前を指定する */
    public NormalComputerPlayer(String name) {
    super(name);
    // 手を設定する
    goo = new Goo();
    choki = new Choki();
    par = new Par();
    random = new java.util.Random();
    }

    /** match回目の勝負のnum回目のプレイヤの手を出す
     *  Player の showHand をオーバーライド
     */
    public Hand showHand(int match, int num) {
    int hand = random.nextInt(3);
    if (hand == 0) {
        return goo;
    } else if (hand == 1) {
        return choki;
    } else {
        return par;
    }
    }
}
```

```
/** ジャンケンを開始するためのクラス */
public class Janken {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Judge judge = new Judge(); // 審判の作成

        // プレイヤの作成と審判への登録
        Player jhon = new OrderedComputerPlayer("Jhon");
        judge.registPlayer(jhon);
        Player paul = new NormalComputerPlayer("Paul");
        judge.registPlayer(paul);

        // 3回勝負でジャンケンの開始
        judge.startJankens(3);
    }
    catch (JankenException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

```
/** ジャンケン プレイヤの抽象クラス */
public abstract class Player {
    protected String name;     // プレイヤの名前
    protected int    matches;  // matches回勝負(matches回先に勝った方が勝ち)
    protected int    wins;     // プレイヤの勝利数
    protected int    losts;    // プレイヤの負け数

    /** コンストラクタ, プレイヤの名前を指定する */
    public Player(String name) {
    this.name = name;   // プレイヤの名前
    wins = losts = 0;   // 勝敗を初期化
    }

    /** プレイヤの名前を返す */
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    /** 何回勝負か設定するメソッド
     */
    public void setMatches(int matches) {
    this.matches = matches;
    }

    /** 
     *   勝ったことを知らされるメソッド
     */
    public void youWon() {
    wins++;
    }

    /** 
     *   負けたことを知らされるメソッド
     */
    public void youLost() {
    losts++;
    }


    /** match回目の勝負のnum回目のプレイヤの手を出す
     *   抽象メソッドなので，サブクラスでオーバーライドする
     */
    public abstract Hand showHand(int match, int num);
}
```

**実行結果:**

```
$ java Janken
Match 1: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 1-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-2:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Goo

Match 1: Jhon won.

Match 2: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 2-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Par

Match 2: Paul won.

Match 3: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 3-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Choki

Match 3: Jhon won.

Match 4: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 4-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 4-2:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Choki

Match 4: Paul won.

Match 5: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 5-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Choki

Match 5: Jhon won.

Jhon is a champion.
Jhon: 3 wins
Paul: 2 wins
```

<<続き>>
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
switch(match%4)としたところ、以下のようになりました

```
$ java Janken
Match 1: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 1-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-2:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-3:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-4:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-5:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Choki

Match 1: Jhon won.

Match 2: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 2-1:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Par

Aiko de Sho
Match 2-2:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Goo

Match 2: Jhon won.

Match 3: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 3-1:
Jhon's hand is Choki
Paul's hand is Par

Match 3: Jhon won.

Jhon is a champion.
Jhon: 3 wins
Paul: 0 wins
```

これだと、matchが変わるごとにJohnの手が変わってしまい、期待している結果

```
$ java Janken
Match 1: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 1-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Goo

Aiko de Sho
Match 1-2:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Goo

Match 1: Jhon won.

Match 2: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 2-1:
Jhon's hand is Choki
Paul's hand is Par

Match 2: Jhon won.

Match 3: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 3-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Par

Match 3: Paul won.

Match 4: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 4-1:
Jhon's hand is Goo
Paul's hand is Par

Match 4: Paul won.

Match 5: Jan Ken Pon!
Match 5-1:
Jhon's hand is Par
Paul's hand is Goo

Match 5: John won.

Jhon is a champion.
Jhon: 3 wins
Paul: 2 wins
```

のようになりません。

自分のプログラムでは

```
public Hand showHand(int match, int num) {
        
    switch(num%4){
    　　case 1: return goo;
        case 2: return par;
        case 3: return choki; 
        case 0: return goo; 
        }num++;  return goo;
    }
```

となっており、一番最後にreturn goo;としていることで
おそらく勝敗が決まるごとにわざわざリセットされて、グーから始まるのだとは思いますが、return goo;がないとエラーとなってしまいます。

ここで、勝敗が決まっても関係なく、グー、パー、チョキ、グー・・・とするにはどうしたらいいですか。

Comment: (信頼度が低いのでコメントできませんでした)
恐らく、Judgeクラスに問題があると思います。
Judgeクラスを見せてください。

Comment: Judgeクラスに問題はありません（すでに作成されたプログラムで、それをもとに作成しているため）。明らかにOrderedComputerPlayerのswitch文がおかしいのだと思いました。

Comment: 実行結果を見ると、Jhon の手は `1-1`, `2-1`, `3-1`, `4-1`, `5-1` では `Goo` で、`1-2`, `4-2` では `Par` になっています。つまり、`showHand(int match, int num)` の呼び出し方の問題と思われます。実際には `switch(num%4)` は `switch(match%4)` とするのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

まだ省略されているコードがあるように見えるので憶測を含みますが、`num` 回目の変数は `match` 勝負目に応じて都度リセットされるわけですから「ゲームを通して今何回目か」を管理する別の変数を用意し、そちらでどの手を出すか決めるようにすれば良さそうです。

つまり、`showHand` に渡すのは、`match` や `num` じゃなくて「今何回目か」を表す変数に変更する。